# Weight enumerators for Hermitian operator (wrong $ B_j $ definition)

Tags: error-correction, mathematics, linear-algebra

Let $ H $ be Hermitian operator on an $ n $ qubit Hilbert space $ \mathbb{C}^{2^n} $. Define the weight enumerator coefficients
$$
A_j=\frac{1}{(Tr(H))^2} \sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}_j} |tr(EH)|^2
$$
where $ \mathcal{E}_j $ is the set of all Paulis of weight $ j $.
And define the dual weight enumerator coefficients
$$
B_j=\frac{1}{Tr(H)} \sum_{ E \in \mathcal{E}_j} tr(EH E^{\dagger} H).
$$
Is it the case that
$$
B_j \geq A_j
$$
for all $ j $?

Note that if $ H $ is a projector, i.e. $ H^\dagger=H $ and $ H^2=H $ then this is a standard result from the theory of weight enumerators. I am wondering if it is still true when $ H $ is Hermitian but not necessarily a projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No. Suppose that $H=\alpha H'$ for some scale factor $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. The key observation is that $A_j$ is independent of $\alpha$, but $B_j$ is linear in $\alpha$. We can use this to construct counterexamples for any $j$.

For instance, we can proceed as follows for $j=0$ . Let $H=\alpha |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ be a scalar multiple of a rank one projector with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
A_0&=\frac{1}{(\mathrm{tr}(H))^2}|\mathrm{tr}(H)|^2=1\tag1\\
B_0&=\frac{1}{\mathrm{tr}(H)}\mathrm{tr}(H^2)=\alpha\tag2
\end{align}
$$
and we obtain a counterexample for any $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: As you point out the way I defined $ B_j $ was the wrong generalization. I should divide by $ tr(H^2) $ in the definition of the $ B_j $. As is done for example in equation (4) of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9610040. Do you know a counterexample for the correct definition of the $ B_j $? Also I know it is bad manners to go back and change the question after it has already been answered, what do you advise I do in this case? I really meant to ask this with $ tr(H^2) $ in the denominator for $ B_j $. Should I go back and change it? Ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, please ask a new question. It costs little and results in better content on the site. Consider also linking from one question to the other.

Comment: Done! New question is here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31611/weight-enumerators-for-hermitian-operator and includes a link to this question